# Series manipulation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following problem: let us define
$$A_k = \sum_{m = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{c_m}{(m!)^2 (m+1)(m+k)},$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that for $k > 1$ all $A_k$ are known. Is there a way (a trick) to compute $A_1$ in terms of $A_k$?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How are defined the $c_m$'s ?

Comment: They are given as $P_m^{(0,-2m - 2)}(d)$, where $d$ is a constant and $P_m^{(a,b)}$ stands for the Jacobi's polynomials.